# html2pdf.js - Div content moving downwards

Tags: html2pdf

I am using html2pdf.js library, but all contents from any html tag is moving downwards. [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HpQl.png) shows an example of the problem. The code to this part is:

```
<div class="text-xs text-neutral-70 bg-orange-200">
    Lorem ipsum<br>
    Lorem<br>
    ipsum
</div>

<div class="text-xs bg-green-400">
    <a :href="baseUrl" target="_blank">
        lorem.ipsum/
    </a>
</div>
```

I am trying to fit the content to the div, just like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ua0RL.png). I have tried to change margins, paddings and leading settings, but none of them seems to have any effect.